# Device won't reboot after SPI flash package changed

Tags: pcb-design, spi, flash

Have custom linux driven hardware with bootloader and linux image stored at SPI nor flash IC W25Q128JVSIQ in SOIC-8 package.

[image]

Now I need more memory (32Mb instead of 16Mb). Unfortunately bigger memory exists only in different packages. One of the available package - is WSON 8x6. So I replaced used one W25Q128JVSIQ (SOIC-8) with W25Q256JVEIQ (WSON 8x6mm). Pin to pin compatible (I guess):

[image]

It works at first glance. Linux kernel loads at power up but won't restart at rebooting. When I send `reboot` command I see `reboot: Restarting system` log message and nothing more after. Device doesn't restart. Same hardware (except Flash IC), same PCB, same firmware flashed in both SPI flash ICs. So I am pretty sure there is not software related issue. After replacing WSON flash IC with another in SOIC package with same firmware device started to reboot as expected.
The only thing that comes to my mind is no connection of metal pad at the bottom of IC. No mention of that pad in [datasheet](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q256jv%20spi%20revg%2008032017.pdf). So is that might be a reason of such strange issue? If not what else might lead to that? Tried to play with pull up resistors (on the second photo) on SPI lines - no luck.

Comment: *So I am pretty sure there is not software related issue* - I am pretty sure it is. But we can only guess.

Comment: Do you have scope traces showing what replies are observed from the flash after the reboot is attempted? Or any remarks as to what control/configuration registers are set to at boot, assumed at boot, and set at reboot?

Comment: They are pin-compatible alright. But have you double-checked your soldering work, it seems you had some issues when replacing the chip. Also, since the 16-Mbyte device only works with 3-byte addresses, and the 32-Mbyte device can natively work with 4-byte addresses, have you checked if they are protocol-compatible or can the iMX be set to control larger chip natively? Simply extending a filesystem from 32MB to 64MB will not work.

Comment: @nanofarad, checked using oscilloscope that there exchange exists on all lines of SPI after reboot so first stage bootloader communicates with SPI flash IC but U-boot doesn't start. Thought to re-order PCB with metal pad connected to GND.

Comment: @user3583807 It communicates -- what are the responses? The parts you mention can be switched into and out of various modes including ones that affect the addressing.

Comment: @Justme, CPU boots from 32Mb flash IC successfully but won't restart after reboot.

Comment: @user3583807 Exactly, what if some driver does some bank switching and leaves the 3-byte addressing to access the non-default high 32Mbytes instead of the default powerup state of accessing the low 32 Mbytes, so it tries to reboot from the wrong half of the chip?

Comment: @nanofarad, I will check using logic analyzer while waiting for new revision of PCB. Thank you!

Comment: @Justme, both SPI flash IC flashed using same 5Mb size firmware. Lower part of addressing space, I guess. But yeah, seems I need to check SPI packets using logic analyzer, thank you!

Comment: Also scope those signals, to make sure the logic analyzer is reporting "real" data.  LA can't show reflections or slow rise-times.

Comment: found bug description that looks very similar to my case: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/How-do-you-change-a-QSPI-device-from-4-byte-addressing-back-to-3/m-p/991471
Looking a way to apply patch

Comment: In many cases the bootloader is UBOOT. Depending on the build, it might read the id of the flash chip and get upset if it is not what it expects. Similarly with the flash driver in the kernel. Different flash chips may have differing erase sizes, block sizes and so on. Thus it might not be a simple operation to use a different flash chip. Eg to upgrade a wr703 wifi router with a larger flash chip you need a new boot loader, a linux kernel built for the flash chip and the correct part number flash chip. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: patched kernel by sending reset sequence SPI commands (0x66 and 0x99 in sequence) as explained in datasheet: https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q256jv%20spi%20revg%2008032017.pdf. It helped partially. Device boots after reboot but there are about 120 seconds between last log message before rebooting and first u-boot message. E.g. fsbl able to boot from SPI IC but with too long delay. Any suggestions why it happens?

Comment: magically, device started to reboot without any delay after few delayed reboots so yeah, your suggestions about registers modification on linux kernel loading was correct. So could someone post their comment as answer so I can vote it, @nanofarad, Justme, rdtsc, Kartman? Thank you very much for pointing me to the solution!

Comment: @user3583807 posted a "community wiki" answer -- please feel free to edit and add any findings of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The larger device is suspected to cause the kernel to switch it between modes of operation/memory banks, which puts it into an unexpected state after the reboot. This causes reads to either return unexpected data or nothing at all.

A reset command, specially `0x66 0x99` seems to work for this device.

Comment: Thank you very much!